# In client side JavaScript, can any element besides window get a resize event?

Tags: javascript, dom

I get multiple pages saying that the resize event can be on a `body` or `div` element:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onresize.asp

http://v3.javascriptmvc.com/docs/jQuery.event.special.resize.html#&who=jQuery.event.special.resize

but then I tried it in jsfiddle or in a standalone page and never can get a resize event on an element:

http://jsfiddle.net/sgHck/1/

http://jsfiddle.net/sgHck/8/

Can `body` or `div` get a resize event at all?   If not, what if we need to shrink a section down in the page, and part of the page relies on the `scroll` event to properly place another element, and the `resize` event for the document, not the window, will also be needed as well?

Comment: Your event fires for me in Firefox. And it fires for me in Chrome when I give the `body` some dimension. http://jsfiddle.net/sgHck/9/

Comment: On iPad the body resize event fires when rotating the device

Comment: but when you click on the "add" button many times so that the body now is now bigger than when it first loaded, neither does the `body` or the `#content` gets the event. Try http://jsfiddle.net/sgHck/14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging around a bit it appears that they can have resize events just not quite in the way you want.

You can add a resize event like this

```
$('#content').resize( function(){
    //stuff to do
}
```

or

```
$('#content').on('resize', function(){
    //stuff to do
}
```

which you are already doing, but these just don't fire when the elements are resized by javascript code or anything like that. the only way to trigger it this way is with

```
$('#content').trigger('resize');
```

which you can really do with any string. This does propagate up through the dom tree. Say you had the #content inside of a body with a 'resize' event on both of them. If you trigger the #content it will also trigger the body. However, if you trigger the event with body it will not trigger the #content.

However it seems you can get the type of functionality you want with the jquery-ui resizable method http://jqueryui.com/resizable/. After you make something resizable with

```
$('#content').resizable({options});
```

it should trigger the resize event if they are changed.